# Animation works not correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a block, when changing dynamic height. Open animation works correct, but when im closing block, animation drops, cant undestand why.

Link: `dev.divisory.com/6/`

code example:

```
let linetags_more = (e) => {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  let container = e.target.closest(".js-line-tags");
  let spc = e.target.closest(".js-line-tags").querySelector(".line-tags__wrap").clientHeight;
  const box = container.querySelector(".line-tags__box");


  if(container.classList.contains("js-line-tags__more--active")) {
    container.classList.remove("js-line-tags__more--active");
    box.style.maxHeight = spc+"px";
  
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      box.style.maxHeight = row+"px";
    }, 100);

    
  } else {
    
    box.style.maxHeight = spc+"px";
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      container.classList.add("js-line-tags__more--active");
      box.removeAttribute("style");
    }, 200);
  }

  e.preventDefault();  
}
```

[image]

Comment: share your html. It's needed to advice

Comment: U can see it on link

Comment: Height can be dynamic, i cant set maxHeight from css

Comment: im not undestanding the problem

Comment: Why do you need `box.removeAttribute("style")`?

Comment: Cuz content iside spoiler can be changed, and window can be resized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `box.removeAttribute("style")`. Just remove it and everything going to be OK.

```
if (container.classList.contains("js-line-tags__more--active")) {
    container.classList.remove("js-line-tags__more--active");
    box.style.maxHeight = spc + "px";

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        box.style.maxHeight = "60" + "px";
    }, 100);


} else {

    box.style.maxHeight = spc + "px";
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        container.classList.add("js-line-tags__more--active");
        //box.removeAttribute("style");
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: I cant. Cuz window can be resized or content inside can be changed.